# Sending Combo Key action simulating DirectInput

Tags: autohotkey

I found this useful script on this [thread](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/785-a-program-that-defeats-autohotkey/page-9) to remap a key on a game.

```
T::
SetKeyDelay,300
Send {Blind}{b DownTemp}
Send {Blind}{b Up}
```

It works for the game I'm playing but I have not figured it out for a more sophisticated command like remapping T to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>?

I thought of changing the script like this, but it doesn't work:

```
T::
SetKeyDelay,300
Send {Blind}{Ctrl DownTemp}
Send {Blind}{b DownTemp}
Send {Blind}{b Up}
Send {Blind}{Ctrl Up}
return
```

Comment: You're sending CTRL+z in your script. Also, it is reasonable in most cases to complete a hotkey label with a `return` at the end.

Comment: Yes I'm sending Ctrl+Z but it doesn't matter if Ctrl+Z is another one I want to bind.. so for simplicity pretend Z=B. I'll put the return at the end of the script.. I think that's what you mean

Comment: changed z to b to avoid confusions. thx MCL

Comment: So...? *"It doesn't work"* is a rather poor description and sounds more like "please someone debug it for me". If I'm mistaken, please share what your debugging efforts have yielded: Does the hotkey trigger? Does the Send sequence work in other windows? Why are you using `{Blind}` or `DownTemp`, respectively; and what happens if you omit either one or both in one or multiple `Send` commands? Did you try different `SendMode`s and the `{Raw}` precursor? Those are the kinds of questions you have to ask yourself and then answer.

Comment: Btw: You don't need to be a virtuoso to figure out those questions, reading the [docs](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Send.htm) with good care is often enough.

Comment: My question is very simple, and if you can't answer it then just tell me that you cannot. Don't give me a sermon about reading documentation yadda yadda! I read the documentation, and there is nothing that really covers DirectInput. There is one question in the FAQ that explains how one might get around it, but when I try the suggested code "it doesn't work." I don't know why it doesn't work, I have no experience in debugging this scripts, and not exactly what to use in order to find a better reason why the program isn't doing what is expected.

Comment: Also, working around DirectInput isn't trivial! Why do you think there are all those posts on that thread that I put a link to. Anyway, your suggestions are useful, and some of them can be helpful to understand the problem better. I just need to know what tool to use to investigate more closely why it isn't working. Doing what you suggested can take an aweful long amount of time. Trying all sorts of different combinations of key delays and modes, that's why I asked the question in the first place, someone might know exactly why it isn't working.

Comment: Well, judging by the absence of answers, I guess your plan to receive the magical answer has failed. Debugging is nothing specific to AHK, except that out of the box, there are no convenient tools like breakpoint debuggers or consoles (which nonetheless do exist). For basic use cases, `MsgBox`, `TrayTip` or writing to a log file are alternatives. In your case, you don't even really need any of those, since it's more of a trial and error type of problem.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I may be of help guiding you to a solution or even testing out stuff myself. But if I get the feeling that you're not willing to (and in fact did not) do your own testing and playing around, I, and probably others are less inclined to do so ourselves. Anyhow, It could be that `{CTRL downtemp}` is the problem. Try replacing it with `{CTRL down}`.

Comment: I haven't had much time to look back at it MCL. So yes, my hope for a magical answer failed. Because this is just something I'm trying to do for fun and not job-related, I can't put too much time into it. And.. unfortunately it isn't that high in my list of things to do. I really appreciate your suggestions, and will try them out when I get the time to get back to it. I will also report what I see here.